# How to hide the bookmark bar?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I would like to completely disable the bookmark bar from Google Chrome and I don't find any information on the web.

If I disable the bookmark bar, it still appears in an embedded bar to the Google search page. 
[image]

If I right click and select "Show bookmark bar" I see this:
[image]

Of course If I go to the bookmark manager and delete all the useless bookmarks I will still see the bar:

[image]

How can I just disable it?

Comment: CTRL-SHIFT-B hotkey will hide the bar.

Comment: @Chloe, not from the new tab page

Comment: CMD+SHIFT+B for mac users

Comment: ctrl+shift+B doesn't hide it for me, just moved a line in between the bookmark bar and the address bar, but the bookmarks still appear in the new tab page.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From what I know and have found in the past, it's impossible to completely remove the embedded bookmarks bar from the New Tab page. Even if you have the Show Bookmark Bar disabled within Chrome, it will show an alternate embedded version of the bar within that page.

You do have 2 options:

1. Move your bookmarks from the bookmarks bar to a different folder (`Bookmarks > Manage Bookmarks`).
2. [Set up a homepage](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314?hl=en) other than the New Tab page, so when you start Chrome you won't see them.

Comment: The homepage option isn't working for me. I already have https://www.google.com/ set as my homepage in chrome://settings/?search=home. And I've hidden the Bookmarks Bar. But when I open a new Incognito window, the same bookmarks appear at the top, but with a line above them (as other people have mentioned here). I want to be able to easily record screencasts without showing my personal bookmarks. And I don't want to have to move them every time.

Answer (score 36):

Both, what deltab and CustomX have mentioned are rather correct.

Chrome Bookmarks Bar's visibility can be toggled on all pages except for the New Tab page.
To toggle, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on Mac, or simply open the `View` menu and select `Always Show Bookmarks Bar`.

Why Google has done this, I don't know, but you can check how the Bookmarks Bar is toggled by using the above shortcuts on any web page other than the New Tab page (e.g: go to www.google.com and try).

Answer (score 9):

Chrome's default new tab page (NTP) always shows a bookmark bar, even if you turn it off for other pages. You can however install browser extensions which replace the NTP, and the replacements do not automatically get the bookmarks bar (but can with some extra programming).

So for instance Google's [Earth View](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/earth-view-from-google-ma/bhloflhklmhfpedakmangadcdofhnnoh?utm=omgchrome) extension does not show bookmarks, whereas [Pinterest's now does](http://www.omgchrome.com/pinterest-new-tab-page-bookmarks-update/).